# Import CSV file to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I'm trying to import a CSV file into another sheet when I press a button on one sheet.

Here is my code:

```
Sub historiskAktieData(ticker)

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("HistoriskAktieData")
    Dim enddate As Date
    Dim StartDate As Date

    StartDate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Opg. 1").Range("c1").Value
    enddate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Opg. 1").Range("c2").Value
    Symbol = ticker

    qurl = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" & Symbol & "&a=" & Month(StartDate) - 1 & "&b=" & Day(StartDate) & "&c=" & Year(StartDate) & "&d=" & Month(enddate) - 1 & "&e=" & Day(enddate) & "&f=" & Year(enddate) & "&g=" & "" & "&q=q&y=0&z=" & Symbol & "&x=.csv"

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & qurl _
    , Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
    .Name = "table.csv?s=SAP&a=01&b=01&c=14&d=01&e=08&f=16&g=Dateq=q&y=0&z=&x="
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 850
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

The problem seems to be this bit:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & qurl _
    , Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
```

Hope someone can help. I'm using excel 2010.

Answer (score 0):

From
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837764.aspx

> Destination, Required, Range
>
> The cell in the upper-left corner of the query table destination range
>   (the range where the resulting query table will be placed). The
>   destination range must be on the worksheet that contains the
>   QueryTables object specified by expression.

The QueryTable you are trying to create is in your active sheet (ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(...)), yet Destination:=ws.Range("A1") is in general not in the same sheet. Simply write ws.QueryTables.Add(...) instead of ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(...).